# Animating WPF element in XAML using attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I got my animation to work triggered by a property in my ViewModel. If I set my `TargetProperty` to `Width`, the below code actually works in growing the image.

Next, I wanted to actually move the image up and down. To do this, I added a `Canvas` component around my image, to be able to animate based on `Canvas.Top` property. Setting `Canvas.Top` on the image moves it where I want.

However, if I set my `StoryBoard.TargetProperty` to `Canvas.Top`, I get an error:

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path
>   Canvas.Top.

```
<Style x:Key="LoadingImageAnimation" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="True">
      <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation From="10" To="250" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:30"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is my approach totally off, or just a matter of finding the Attached Property?

Comment: Try `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did some digging around on [Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), and the solution was actually simple. Needed to add parentheses:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
```

The animation is not as smooth as i would like.. but at least it works now.