# Exception using Grid.Left as a TargetProperty of a Rectangle in a DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, storyboard

I have a `Rectangle` isnide a `Canvas` and I want to **move it** from the top left corner to the bottom right one, **using** the framework's **animations**. I chose to use `DoubleAnimation` in order to manipulate the `Grid.Left` and `Grid.Top` properties of the rectangle, as seen bellow,

```xml
<Rectangle Name="MyRectangle"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Fill="Blue"
                   Canvas.Left="0"
                   Canvas.Top="0">
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Left"
                                            From="0"
                                            To="690"
                                            Duration="0:0:5"
                                            AutoReverse="True"
                                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top"
                                             From="0"
                                             To="340"
                                             Duration="0:0:5"
                                             AutoReverse="True"
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
```

Unfortunately, when I run the application I **get a runtime exception** stating that,

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path
>   'Canvas.Left'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

1. Does this mean that I am not allowed to manipulate attached
   properties in such animation scenarios?
2. In case I am not allowed, how I am supposed to manipulate
   `Grid.Left` and `Grid.Top` for a child element?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048226/animating-wpf-element-in-xaml-using-attached-property). Attached properties have different syntax

Comment: Damn and I tried to search about it and couldn't find that. Thanks @Eldar!